# Aireplay --deauth on network with multiple access points

Tags: aircrack-ng, deauth-attack

I have successfully used the `aireplay-ng --deauth` attack on a network with a single access points, but when trying on a network with multiple access points (e.g. a network using Google WiFi) it doesn't seem to work. From what I understand, the device automatically switches the connection to another access point on the network.

How would one go about running an `aireplay-ng --deauth` attack on a network with multiple access points? Please provide example code if possible.

I have attempted to deauth a specific client using the full `aireplay-ng --deauth 1000000 -a [router MAC] -c [client MAC] mon0`. But from what I understand, you can only specify one access point, so when the client disconnects from that access point it automatically connects to another access point on the network.

Solution:
Thanks for the help everyone! The thing is that they are not all on the same channel for some reason. The way I was able to accomplish it was to cycle through the three channels and also send out deauthentication to all three channels in a loop until it works.

Comment: I remember reading that the client connects to the next AP with strongest broadcast so you will have to do that..other than that i am out of ideas

Comment: are you capturing the handshake or doing an evil twin attack?

Comment: @VipulNair capturing the handshake

Comment: Why not airodump all the AP that way when it does connect to another one you will capture the handshake

Comment: @VipulNair Great idea! I'm relatively new to this (am in the middle of a beginners course). I tried running airodump-ng against all three routers using the -m option. It seems to be running fine but when I connected a new device, no handshake was outputted. Any ideas?

Comment: try with : https://github.com/chrizator/netattack2 it should work .. good luck

Comment: If they are on the same channel, what's to stop you from running `n` instances of `aireplay-ng`, one for each access point? If they are on multiple channels, what's to stop you doing that and using multiple adapters or cycling through the channels?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! The thing is that they are not all on the same channel for some reason. The way I was able to accomplish it was to cycle through the three channels and also send out deauthentication to all three channels in a loop until it works.

Comment: @Pvpoe **"...they are not all on the same channel for some reason"** The reason is that that's how you generally setup a multi AP Wi-Fi network, you don't want them to overlap, otherwise they'll make noise on each other. It's the most common setup. On 2.4 Ghz There are actually 3 channels that don't overlap (1, 6 and 11) because of the 20-22 MHz Bandwidth.